# Full text search with entity framework: Cannot use a CONTAINS or FREETEXT predicate on column because it is not full-text indexed

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, full-text-search

I'm using EF 6 and trying to use full text search. I use `IDbCommandInterceptor` to modify query before executing, so result query looks like this:

```
...AND (CONTAINS ([UserFullName], N''Римский ''))
```

The full-text index has been created like this

```
 CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX 
 ON [dbo].[Documents_CreditContracts](UserFullName, FullName, Number, StoreName, UserName) 
 KEY INDEX PK_Documents_CreditContracts
```

and query like this executing well:

```
 SELECT top 1000 *   
 FROM [MKD_OneBillionDollars2].[dbo].[Documents_CreditContracts]  
 WHERE CONTAINS(UserFullName, N'Римский ')
```

but when I'm executing EF query, I get error:

> Cannot use a CONTAINS or FREETEXT predicate on column 'UserFullName' because it is not full-text indexed.

The full EF query:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (10) 
    [Project5].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Project5].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Project5].[DocumentTypeId] AS [DocumentTypeId], 
    [Project5].[Number] AS [Number], 
    [Project5].[FullName] AS [FullName], 
    [Project5].[Amount] AS [Amount], 
    [Project5].[SignDate] AS [SignDate], 
    [Project5].[UserFullName] AS [UserFullName], 
    [Project5].[TableNumber] AS [TableNumber], 
    [Project5].[BankId] AS [BankId], 
    [Project5].[UserBankCode] AS [UserBankCode], 
    [Project5].[StoreName] AS [StoreName], 
    [Project5].[StoreCode] AS [StoreCode], 
    [Project5].[StoreBankCode] AS [StoreBankCode], 
    [Project5].[UserName] AS [UserName]
    FROM ( SELECT [Project5].[Id] AS [Id], [Project5].[DocumentTypeId] AS [DocumentTypeId], [Project5].[Number] AS [Number], [Project5].[FullName] AS [FullName], [Project5].[Amount] AS [Amount], [Project5].[SignDate] AS [SignDate], [Project5].[UserFullName] AS [UserFullName], [Project5].[TableNumber] AS [TableNumber], [Project5].[BankId] AS [BankId], [Project5].[UserBankCode] AS [UserBankCode], [Project5].[StoreName] AS [StoreName], [Project5].[StoreCode] AS [StoreCode], [Project5].[StoreBankCode] AS [StoreBankCode], [Project5].[UserName] AS [UserName], [Project5].[C1] AS [C1], row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Project5].[Id] ASC) AS [row_number]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
            [Project1].[DocumentTypeId] AS [DocumentTypeId], 
            [Project1].[Number] AS [Number], 
            [Project1].[FullName] AS [FullName], 
            [Project1].[Amount] AS [Amount], 
            [Project1].[SignDate] AS [SignDate], 
            [Project1].[UserFullName] AS [UserFullName], 
            [Project1].[TableNumber] AS [TableNumber], 
            [Project1].[BankId] AS [BankId], 
            [Project1].[UserBankCode] AS [UserBankCode], 
            [Project1].[StoreName] AS [StoreName], 
            [Project1].[StoreCode] AS [StoreCode], 
            [Project1].[StoreBankCode] AS [StoreBankCode], 
            [Project1].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
            [Project1].[C1] AS [C1]
            FROM ( SELECT 
                [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
                [Extent1].[DocumentTypeId] AS [DocumentTypeId], 
                [Extent2].[Number] AS [Number], 
                [Extent2].[FullName] AS [FullName], 
                [Extent2].[Amount] AS [Amount], 
                [Extent2].[SignDate] AS [SignDate], 
                [Extent2].[UserFullName] AS [UserFullName], 
                [Extent2].[TableNumber] AS [TableNumber], 
                [Extent2].[BankId] AS [BankId], 
                [Extent2].[UserBankCode] AS [UserBankCode], 
                [Extent2].[StoreName] AS [StoreName], 
                [Extent2].[StoreCode] AS [StoreCode], 
                [Extent2].[StoreBankCode] AS [StoreBankCode], 
                [Extent2].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
                ''0X0X'' AS [C1]
                FROM  [dbo].[Documents] AS [Extent1]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[Documents_CreditContracts] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[Id]
            )  AS [Project1]
            WHERE ( EXISTS (SELECT 
                1 AS [C1]
                FROM   (SELECT [Extent3].[RegisterId] AS [RegisterId], [Extent3].[DocumentId] AS [DocumentId], [Join2].[Id1], [Join2].[C1]
                    FROM  [dbo].[DocumentInPackage] AS [Extent3]
                    INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent4].[Id] AS [Id1], [Project2].[C1] AS [C1]
                        FROM  [dbo].[Registers] AS [Extent4]
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT 
                            [Extent5].[Id] AS [Id], 
                            cast(1 as bit) AS [C1]
                            FROM [dbo].[Registers_CreditContractRegisters] AS [Extent5] ) AS [Project2] ON [Extent4].[Id] = [Project2].[Id] ) AS [Join2] ON [Extent3].[RegisterId] = [Join2].[Id1]
                    WHERE CASE WHEN ( NOT (([Join2].[C1] = 1) AND ([Join2].[C1] IS NOT NULL))) THEN ''5X'' ELSE ''5X0X'' END LIKE ''5X0X%'' ) AS [Filter1]
                LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent6].[Id] AS [Id2], [Project3].[OrpId] AS [OrpId], [Project3].[C1] AS [C1]
                    FROM  [dbo].[Registers] AS [Extent6]
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT 
                        [Extent7].[OrpId] AS [OrpId], 
                        [Extent7].[Id] AS [Id], 
                        cast(1 as bit) AS [C1]
                        FROM [dbo].[Registers_CreditContractRegisters] AS [Extent7] ) AS [Project3] ON [Extent6].[Id] = [Project3].[Id] ) AS [Join4] ON [Filter1].[RegisterId] = [Join4].[Id2]
                WHERE ([Project1].[Id] = [Filter1].[DocumentId]) AND ((CASE WHEN (CASE WHEN ([Join4].[Id2] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ( NOT (([Join4].[C1] = 1) AND ([Join4].[C1] IS NOT NULL))) THEN ''5X'' ELSE ''5X0X'' END LIKE ''5X0X%'') THEN CASE WHEN ([Join4].[Id2] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ( NOT (([Join4].[C1] = 1) AND ([Join4].[C1] IS NOT NULL))) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE [Join4].[OrpId] END END) = @p__linq__0)
            )) AND (CONTAINS ([UserFullName], N''Римский ''))
        )  AS [Project5]
    )  AS [Project5]
    WHERE [Project5].[row_number] > 0
    ORDER BY [Project5].[Id] ASC',N'@p__linq__0 int',@p__linq__0=1
```

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: I'm running into the same problem. I understand why it isn't working but I have not idea how to fix it. The problem is that the Contains statement is trying to run within the context of the [Extent] part of the inner query, which doesn't contain the full text index.

Answer (score 0):

My resolve of problem is to write sql query by hand and execute it. And map results to an EF entities. Lot of work, yeap.

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer is dated relative to when the question was asked, but I found [this answer](http://www.entityframework.info/Home/FullTextSearch) to be helpful in resolving my similar issue.

In the example, you use an interceptor (of type IDbCommandInterceptor) to adjust the SQL generated by the EF6 LINQ query *before* it is executed on the server. This way you can still leverage the LINQ capabilities and not have to build your own complex SQL query generator.

Comment: yeap, i've try it. Wasn't useful for me